# How to set cookie header in post request

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
axios
          .post(
            'https://app.adhg.ashdg/m/api/business/get-business',
            {
              'gid': getgid,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                'Cookie': cookie,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              },
            },
          )
          .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            alert(error.message);
          });
```

I am implementing Axios post request in my React Native application. I want to send formurlencoded parameters along with the header called cookie.

In cookie I am storing AWS token value to send. But I am not getting the response, it says cookie is not sent. The same URL with params working perfectly in Postman. How can I pass cookie in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `Cookie: name=value`.
[Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)